# Is It possible to do a login in facebook passing automatically username and password?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a Db where users save their username and password of facebook. When their open my application should be able to connect into facebook without to insert manually their credential. Is it possible or facebook prohibit it?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use their API instead?

Comment: Apart from the fact that there is no way to do this via API, it is also explicitly not allowed – you are not allowed to ask users for their FB login credentials.

Answer (score -3):

Essentially, social media sites (and all other sites in general) require 'human' submittion (of sorts). It is generally impossible to force login with saved credentials as every time the site gets requested a login token, it automatically checks (and requires) user submitted information.